# Having trouble working with Discord Stickers

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to work around with Discord stickers, but the more I dig, the more confusing it gets.

Sticker URL that we are going to use: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/stickers/781291131828699156.png`

If you copy and paste that URL on discord, it will just show non-animated ("PNG") version of the sticker. But when you send the same sticker on Discord normally using sticker tab or welcome react method, discord will show it as an actual sticker (animated, "GIF"). There are few things I have found while working:

- It will always show PNG version if you are not doing it normally.
- When you type the URL in browser, it will show the actual animated version of the sticker on `.png` format, which is super confusing because it shows "PNG" version all the time when you send the URL in a discord server but when you go to it, it shows animated one. (I am not sure how it works, the page HTML just loads the same URL)
- Discord actually uses `https://media.discordapp.net/stickers/781291131828699156.png?size=160&passthrough=false` when you send the URL normally. I did some research and found out that `cdn` is for desktop and `media` is for mobile. But, its exactly the same as `cdn` one, I am guessing Discord uses "media" as universal because it will load on all devices (not sure).

I tried downloading the file using `axios`, but its the same ("PNG" version).

- Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord uses the [APNG](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) format, which is essentially just letting PNG files be animated, for rendering stickers, so it being `.png` isn't the problem.

As for why it doesn't load, there are a number of reasons why.

1. Your browser might not support the format. This, however, is ruled out as you said in your question that you can load it in a seperate window.
2. It might be the `media` and `cdn` servers messing with the APNG data while compressing the file.

As you found out, Discord uses `media.discordapp.net` as its media proxy for loading images, so that might be at fault. There are known issues about videos loaded from that domain not loading in Discord, so that might be related.

I've tested this myself, and it looks like a) if you load the `media` link in your browser, it **won't** animate (at least for me), and b) if you send it in Discord, it also **won't** animate.

The `cdn` link, however, is a tiny bit different. I found out that a) it **does**, actually, animate on my browser (like what happened to yours) but b) **does not** animate in Discord.

So we know what happens on `media` is different from `cdn`. Maybe this is why?

My current theory is that Discord might strip unneeded (in its opinion) data from the PNG file (thinking it's not APNG) to cut down on bandwidth usage, which prevents it from animating.

I'll have to investigate this further, though.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your time and research, I really appreciate it.  Just to let you know, I solved it by using puppeteer and other methods (I will make a post below). But my method is pretty slow, so figuring out a faster method would be super handy.